# PHP DOMDocument schemaValidate but get type

Tags: php, xml

Sa I have two types of schemas, one for `<Request>` and one for `<Response>`. I have the schema xsd for both.

I want to be able to get the "type" of the schema, even if it is invalid. For example, `<Request to2="">...` should be invalid, but I want to still know that this is a `Request`.

The problem is `$xml->schemaValidate(...)` will return `false` for both of my schemas if the attributes are also wrong.

(this example is simplified, in reality, I can have multiple verbs for each schema types, so I don't want to iterate through the child nodes and check what the nodeType is).

Is there a way to use DOMDocument to validate the choice only (no attribute validation)?

For instance:

```
<Request>...</Request>                      ---> {type: 'Request', isValid: true},
<Response>...</Response>                    ---> {type: 'Response', isValid: true},

<Request to="api/action">...</Request>      ---> {type: 'Request', isValid: true},
<Request tooo="api/action">...</Request>    ---> {type: 'Request', isValid: false},

<Response type="json">...</Response>        ---> {type: 'Response', isValid: true},
<Response typeeee="json">...</Response>     ---> {type: 'Response', isValid: false},
```

If I juse use `$xml->schemaValidate('/path/to/request.xsd');` and `$xml->schemaValidate('/path/to/response.xsd');` I will not be able to determine the type of `<Request tooo="api/action">...</Request>` and `<Response typeeee="json">...</Response>` respectively because they are "invalid"

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a combined XSD that validates both types according to their tag name.